# MySQL normalizing data not always present

Tags: mysql, normalization

I'm storing the information for Magic the Gathering cards in a data base, my doubt is how to store information that is not always present.

i.e. creatures have a power/toughness, while other cards don't. should I store it for every card and leave it empty for the ones that don't have it? or create another table to store this information, like:

```
cardID power resist
```

how would this affect query times?

Comment: there's only a few thousand mtg cards. worrying about speed on such a SMALL dataset would only be a problem if your DB server was an incredibly underpowered machine, in which case you've got bigger problems than just a slow database.

Comment: This might help: http://www.dcs.warwick.ac.uk/~hugh/TTM/Missing-info-without-nulls.pdf

Comment: @MarcB Hmm good to know it won't take much on the server, in this case using the extra table is the correct way?

Comment: @proskor Ty, I'll read this with more focus when I'm off work... look like what I need.

Answer (score 0):

From a normalization point of view, power and resistance are functionally dependent from the cardID, and should thus be on the same table as all the other things which depend from the cardID.
If I correctly remember how magic works, you would have one big table with several columns for all the features of a card: power, resistance, cost (which I would model as a VARCHAR), picture.
Then, since a 1-N (or M-N, don't remember) relationship exists between effects and cards, you will have an extra table with the effects, which use the cardID as a foreign key (or maybe a dispatch table, if it's M-N).

Anyway, I found only 4 fields + ID for the cards, it isn't so much you have to worry, it's quite a litte, rather. Even if you wanted to model the cost as multiple INTs, the number of elements is limited (5-6?). A table with 10, or even 20 columns is not a problem for a DBMS.
Maybe yo're going to have a worse time concerning the effects (if you're planning to implement them).